# Voice over "double tap to edit" issue

Tags: iphone, ios7, voiceover

In my iPhone application I use voice over and braille board. In viewWillAppear I set focus and call becomefirstresponder of UITextView element. But even after becomefirstresponder call, Voice over say "Double Tap To edit" not "TextField is editing". Please help. I am trying to fix this issue for two days long.

Here is my code:

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    [self performSelector:@selector(setFocus) withObject:nil afterDelay:1];

}

-(void) setFocus{
        UIAccessibilityPostNotification(UIAccessibilityScreenChangedNotification,  textFieldMain);
        [textFieldMain becomeFirstResponder];


}
```

Comment: What happens if you wait until viewDidAppear?

Comment: I have tried to call becomefirstresponder in viewDidAppear also

Comment: Do you become first responder before or after setting focus?

Comment: I have updated my question with code

Comment: So does it matter if you becomeFirstResponder before?

Comment: It seems that not. I have tested with both variants